# How do I make webpack resolve dependencies relative to the package root in a monorepo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, yarn-workspaces

I've got a yarn 3 workspace monorepo with a `package.json` that looks (in part) like this:

```
  "name": "myweb",
  "workspaces": [
    "client/*"
  ],
```

The directory structure of interest looks like this:

```
client/
  client-A/
    index.js
    src/
      components/
        AThing1.jsx
        AThing2.jsx
  client-B/
    src/
      components/
        BThing.jsx
```

Inside of `client/client-A`, we have:

```
// File: client-A/index.js

export { default as AThing1 } from './components/AThing1'
```

```
// File: client-A/AThing1.jsx

import AThing2 from 'components/AThing2'
```

In `client/client-B`, there's this:

```
// File: client-B/BThing.jsx

import { AThing1 } from '@myweb/client-A'
```

When I try to run webpack 5 development server in `client-B`, I get this error:

```
ERROR in ../client-A/src/components/AThing1.jsx ...
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'components/AThing2' in '/workplace/termly_web/client/client-A/src/components/AThing1'
```

It seems pretty clear to me that it's trying to find `components/AThing2` within `client/client-B/src`, which is not what I want. What I need it to do is to resolve `components/AThing2` **in the context of its own package, namely `client/client-A/src`**.

The `client-B` webpack does not seem to take into account `client/client-A/babel.config.js` or anything in `client/client-A/webpack.config.js`.

I've tried adding the path to `client/client-A/src` to the `resolve.modules` and `resolve.roots` arrays in the `client-B` webpack config, but to no avail. I've also tried `resolve.preferRelative = true`, but that didn't work either.

The simplest solution, based upon the minimalistic example code above, would be to simply use `import AThing2 from './components/AThing2'`, but this is impractical because the actual directory structure I'm dealing with is fairly deep and would require a ton of backtracking (e.g. `from '../../../../components/Foo'`), which is something I'm not willing to do. I would also prefer not to change every single file in `client-A` to use a `@myweb/` prefix on every single import.

This feels like it should be a pretty simple problem to solve. What am I missing?

Here are the configs I'm working with:

```
// File: client/client-B/webpack.config.js
// Heavily redacted to eliminate noise...

[...snip...]

    resolve: {
      modules: [
        'src',
        'node_modules',
      ],
      roots: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      ],
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.scss', '.css', '.sass'],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: [
            {
              and: [/node_modules/],
              not: [/@mycompany\/react-components\/src/],
            },
          ],
          loader:  'babel-loader',
        },

[...snip...]
```

```
// File: client/client-B/babel.config.js

module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@babel/preset-env',
    '@babel/preset-react',
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        alias: {
          'test': './test',
          'react': '../../node_modules/react',
          'react-dom': '../../node_modules/react-dom',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
  env: {
    production: {
      plugins: [
        'transform-react-remove-prop-types',
      ],
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Have you found how to do ?
I'm having a similar issue in a monorepo using pnpm workspace. Using "workspace:" prefix helped getting rid of Module not found errors in my case. But Issues with packaging remain